# Unable to use inbuild wordcount jar file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am struggling with the below code. can any one help me to sort out.

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop jar /usr/lib;

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job   jar:    /usr/lib
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:135)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:133)

[cloudera@localhost ~]$
```

I want to run the wordcount example jar in hadoop itself.But its not allowing to use the inbuild jar

Thanks,
Anbu k.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to an actual jar. `"/usr/lib"` is not a jar file. Refer to [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html) for the commands.

Comment: Yes i knew this. but when i want to use the predefined jars for word count in hadoop, How could i proceed?
Thanks,
Anbu k

Answer (score 0):

Try following command. Assuming, $HADOOP_HOME is declared and you have copied input data to HDFS.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-*-examples.jar wordcount your_input_path your_output_path
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply.

[cloudera@localhost ~]$ HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-*-examples.jar Wcount /home/cloudera/Desktop/words /home/cloudera/Desktop/words/output
bash: HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-*-examples.jar Wcount /home/cloudera/Desktop/words /home/cloudera/Desktop/words/output
bash: HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop: No such file or directory

but its not working for me.

Thanks,
Anbu k